# D3 Fisheye Distortion on simple Scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot, fisheye

I'm trying to implement the d3 fisheye distortion (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) on a simple scatter plot.

Here the code that I have so far:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yDWld6?p=preview

I am very unsure how I should call the circles for the distortion. At the moment it looks like this but nothing happens on "mousemove" so far.

```
svg.on("mousemove", function() {
  fisheye.center(d3.mouse(this));

  circles
    .selectAll("circle")
    .each(function (d) { d.fisheye = fisheye(d); })
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.fisheye.pages })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.fisheye.books });
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prepare the data for the fisheye plugin:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .datum( function(d) {
        return {x: d.pages, y: d.books} // change data, to feed to the fisheye plugin
    })
    .attr("cx", function (d) {return d.x}) // changed data can be used here as well
    .attr("cy", function (d) {return d.y}) // ...and here
    .attr("r", 2);

...

// now we can pass in the d.x and d.y values expected by the fisheye plugin...
circles.each(function(d) { d.fisheye = fisheye(d); })
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.fisheye.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.fisheye.y; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.fisheye.z * 2; });
});
```

I also made changes to the declaration of the fisheye in accordance with the latest [official version](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/fisheye/fisheye.js) of the plugin which I used in the plunk linked below.

So, here is a [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/7JGBSS?p=preview) with the fisheye distortion applied to the scatterplot.

Comment: @kim YMW. I am glad to help. I checked your website...important work on blood money, a big and ever-present problem. Well done.