# D3 js selectAll each doesn't iterate

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement the [FishEye lens (Cartesian)](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/#cartesian) in my scatterplot.
I am trying to follow [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407421/d3-fisheye-distortion-on-simple-scatter-plot), but apparently my selector already fails.

I have my FishEye defined as

```
var fisheye = d3.fisheye.circular().radius(120);

svg.on("mousemove", function() {
    fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));

    console.log("here " + points.selectAll("circle").length);

    points.selectAll("circle").each(function(d) {
        console.log("aaa");
        d.fisheye = fisheye(d); 


        /*points.selectAll("circle")
        .each(function(d) { 
            console.log("???");
          this.attr("cx", function(d) {  return d.fisheye.x; })
          this.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.fisheye.y; })
          this.attr("r", function(d) { console.log("hype"); return 10; });
        }); */
    });
});
```

and my points is defined as

```
points = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { // Set the x position using the x-scale
        return x(d.x);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { // Set the y position using the y-scale
        return y(d.y);
    })
    .attr("r", 5) // Set the radius of every point to 5
    .on("mouseover", function(d) { // On mouse over show and set the tooltip
        if(!isBrushing){
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(200)
               .style("opacity", 0.9);

          tooltip.html(d.symbol + "<br/> (" + parseFloat(x(d.x)).toFixed(4)
            + ", " + parseFloat(y(d.y)).toFixed(4) + ")")
               .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        }
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) { // on mouseout, hide the tooltip.
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(500)
               .style("opacity", 0);
      });
```

The console.log with "here" is spamming when I am moving the mouse, and shows the correct amount. Hwoever, the each loop is never executed as I do not see "aaa". I have also tried to just use `selectAll("circle")` but that doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get my FishEye to work?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a jsfiddle. It helps to elicit replies.

Comment: You don't have to use `.selectAll('circle')` again. Since you're storing all your points in the `points` variable, you can just do `points.each(function(d) {...})`

Comment: @Terry You are right, that does show "aaa". My understanding was that points would be the <g> element with the class "point", interesting..

Comment: Remember that you have chained [`.enter()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#enter), therefore from that line onwards `points` will be referring to the collection of `circle` elements instead of their parent `g` ;)

Comment: Add an answer so I can accept it ;)